# ¿Por qué este programa en C me da violación del segmento core al ejecutarlo?

Tags: c

El programa tiene que calcular la posición de particulas de forma aleatoria.

Compila de forma correcta pero a la hora de ejecutarse una vez que introduces el valor de las variables que se solicita mediante scanf, da un error en el **segmento core**.

Basicamente el código necesita crear una matriz donde se almacenan los valores de *x* e *y* tomados de forma aleatoria para crear un documento *.dat* que luego poder introducir en xmgrace.

No tengo claro si puede ser un problema de la matriz. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int i,N;
double f;

printf("Introduce el número de iteraciones: ");
scanf("%d",&N);
printf("Introduce el parámetro f: ");
scanf("%lf",&f);

double x[N], y[N];
double rmax,rmin, restax, restay, distancia;
double xmax=0, ymax=0;
int repite;

x[0]=0; y[0]=0;

FILE * datos;
datos = fopen("DLA.dat","w");

fprintf(datos,"%lf %lf \n",x[0],y[0]);

rmax=1;
for (i=0;i<N;i++){
    repite = 0;
    do{
        rmin=1000000;
        while (rmin > 1){
        x[i+1]=drand48()*(rmax-0)+1;
        y[i+1]=drand48()*(rmax-0)+1;
        x[i+1]= x[i+1] - (f*(x[i+1]/sqrt(pow(x[i+1],2)+pow(y[i+1],2))));
        y[i+1]= y[i+1] - (f*(y[i+1]/sqrt(pow(x[i+1],2)+pow(y[i+1],2))));
        restax = x[i+1]-x[i];
        restay = y[i+1]-y[i];
        rmin = sqrt(pow(restax,2)+pow(restay,2));           
    }
        restax = x[i+1]-x[i];
        restay = y[i+1]-y[i];
        distancia = sqrt(pow(restax,2)+pow(restay,2));
        if (distancia < (2*rmax)+1){
            repite = 1;
        }
    }while (repite==1);


    if (xmax<x[i+1]){
        xmax=x[i+1];
    }
    if (ymax<y[i+1]){
        ymax=y[i+1];
    }
    restax = xmax-x[0];
    restay = ymax-y[0];
    rmax = sqrt(pow(restax,2)+pow(restay,2));

    fprintf(datos,"%lf %lf \n",x[i+1],y[i+1]);          
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En C, el tamaño de una formación<sup>1</sup> debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación. En tu caso lo estás averiguando en tiempo de ejecución:

```
int i, N;
double f;

printf("Introduce el número de iteraciones: ");
scanf("%d", &N);
printf("Introduce el parámetro f: ");
scanf("%lf", &f);

double x[N], y[N]; // N es una variable, no una constante!!!
```

Ésto es conocido como formación de tamaño variable (FTV) o en inglés *variable lenght array* (VLA) y aunque algunos compiladores le dan soporte, no es estándar y puede dar problemas. Hay [varias preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+c+c%2B%2B) en el sitio que puedes consultar para saber más al respecto.

La manera en que debes solucionarlo es alojando memoria dinámicamente:

```
int i, N;
double f;

printf("Introduce el número de iteraciones: ");
scanf("%d", &N);
printf("Introduce el parámetro f: ");
scanf("%lf", &f);

double *x = malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
double *y = malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
```

Cuando acabes de usar `x` e `y`, no olvides liberar la memoria:

```
free(x);
free(y);
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o *array* en inglés.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tú comentario. He modificado el codigo pero ahora simplemente se queda colgado. He puesto un par de print f y se queda colgado justo después de introducir el valor de la variable f.

Comment: @cobraxxiii si la pregunta ha cambiado, deberás editarla. Si la pregunta es diferente, deberás abrir una pregunta nueva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu puntualización :)

Answer (score 0):

en el siguiente buqle:

```
rmin=1000000;
while (rmin > 1){
    x[i+1]=drand48()*(rmax-0)+1;
    y[i+1]=drand48()*(rmax-0)+1;
    x[i+1]= x[i+1] - (f*(x[i+1]/sqrt(pow(x[i+1],2)+pow(y[i+1],2))));
    y[i+1]= y[i+1] - (f*(y[i+1]/sqrt(pow(x[i+1],2)+pow(y[i+1],2))));
    restax = x[i+1]-x[i];
    restay = y[i+1]-y[i];
    rmin = sqrt(pow(restax,2)+pow(restay,2));
}
```

puede que se este haciendo un loop infinito, si la linea `rmin = sqrt(pow(restax,2)+pow(restay,2))` se mantenga siendo un numero mayor que 1.

Comment: Esa opción la habia tenido en cuenta pero el enunciado del programa te obliga a que lo hagas de ese modo.